# Is it possible to filter Contentful results based on a Reference field?

Tags: contentful

I have a Content Type `DonationType` that has a Reference to one `Charity` and I want to perform a query that returns `DonationType`s that have a given Charity. Is this supported by the API? The following attempts don't work:

```
contentful.getEntries({content_type: 'donationType', 'fields.charity': '6eAaZw2TraOgWWE4IG8Ymy'})
contentful.getEntries({content_type: 'donationType', 'fields.charity.id': '6eAaZw2TraOgWWE4IG8Ymy'})
```

Answer (score 2):

you are almost there , the thing is that the id field is inside the sys property, so it should be `fields.charity.sys.id`.
I hope this helps.

Best,
Khaled

Comment: So, does this effectively give us "reverse relations"?  If A has a reference to B, we obviously know about B from A.  But does this let us know about A from B?

Comment: It is not reverse if A has a referece B, you can filter based on that

Comment: Check search params section https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/

Comment: For the record, I tested this answer via raw URL query, and it worked.

Comment: Btw work for Contentful and i am the maintainer of the js sdk

Comment: Great, then answer this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003006/how-do-i-activate-a-contentful-sidebar-extension

Comment: @KhaledGarbaya Is there an 'OR' syntax? The following usage returns all entries with a relationship that contains both 'ALL' and 'VERI' customerId but I need entries that contain either (not both).
 'fields.customers.customerId': ['ALL', 'VERI']