# How do I "activate" a Contentful sidebar extension?

Tags: contentful

I have created a Contentful sidebar extension, which is intended to display other entires which are related to the entry currently loaded in the editor.

I can query the space from CLI tool and my extension is returned, so it was created successfully..  `sidebar` is set to `true` and there's HTML in the `srcdoc` property.

However, when I go to the Contentful interface, nothing has changed -- there is no record of my new extension anywhere, and I can't figure out how to get it to show up anywhere.

Two questions:

1. I had to specify a `fieldTypes` property.  I did: `['Text']`, for lack of any better ideas, even though this extension isn't really meant for a single field, but for the entry as a whole.
2. Do I need to "add" a sidebar extension to a content type? If so, how?  When I modify the content type, the only way to do that seems to be by modifying fields.  Do I add a "pseudo field" to hold the reference to the sidebar extension?
3. Do I need to publish the extension?  It's a Contentful object, like anything else, which makes me think it might need to be published (it's current at version 1), but there doesn't seem to be a method call for this, and it doesn't appear anywhere in the Contentful app interface.

Comment: Could you solve this? According to the documentation at https://github.com/contentful/ui-extensions-sdk#extensions-taxonomy-and-example-use-cases there should be two kinds of extensions: editing and management extensions. I can successfully create editing extensions and bind them to a field using the "Appearance" setting. But I have no idea how to activate a management extension: I can create one and upload it successfully, but it shows up nowhere...

Comment: All I can say is that you don't have to "activate" it.  I had just screwed up the `fieldType` in the JSON. If you do everything right, it should just appear.

Comment: I was in contact with the Contentful support staff in the meantime and it actually is as you pointed out in the comment to Khaled's answer: extensions always have to be bound to a field, even the ones living in the sidebar... So if one wants to do something not specific to a field, one would still need to create a dummy field and bind the extension to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Extension usually show up in the appearance tab in the settings of a field,
More info : https://www.contentful.com/blog/2016/07/06/ui-extensions-sdk/

Comment: I did eventually find it, I just had the `fieldType` wrong. To clarify a point: you always have to bind it to a specific field, even if it's, say, a reporting widget that isn't really storing any data?  For example, say I wanted to make a Google Analytics sidebar widget that showed page views for the entry being edited. This would appear in the sidebar, but I would basically have to create a "fake" field that didn't store any data, but only existed to use for this custom UI sidebar widget. Is that correct?

Comment: You are right that's the whole purpose of the ui extension is to be able to add a facilitator for editing a field that it is supported by The web app, but the idea u had is interesting, i will make sure to pass it to the team